# Clear all reloaded inputs of form

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a form of some inputs that I load them in a **partial view** and I can reset form successfully. When I reload this partial view *by ajax* with some data in them, The form reset button doesn't work at all.

I use jquery for resting form:

> $("form").trigger("reset");

However I can clear inputs by a function that trace all inputs and reset them, but I would like do it with **form reset method**. Any suggestion to do?

**Edit**

```
Jquery:
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        error: function (data) {*handle something here*},
        success: function (data) {
            $("#inputs").html(data);
        }
    });



 Razor:
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveRegistration", "ItemRegister", FormMethod.Post, new
    {
        name = "frmItemRegister"    
    }))
    {
        <div id="inputs">
            @Html.Partial("TestRegister/_RegisterInputs", Model)
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the script where you load the partial view

Comment: @StephenMuecke I put scrips here

Comment: using `.reset()` resets the forms controls to its default values (using the `defaultValue`, `defaultChecked` etc properties). So if your partial is loading form controls that already have values, then those values are the defaults. You can test this by modifying the text, then clicking your rest button - it should revert back to the initial values when you loaded the form via ajax.

Comment: Yes it must works as your explaining. But it won't! After first loading it works well but after ajax not.

Comment: What is it that you are expecting and what are you actually getting? If you have a textbox for a property (say) `FirstName` where the initial value is `null` and then you reload that input with a value (say) "Siamak", the if you changed it to "Something else", then if you click the reset button, are you expecting it to be "Siamak" or an empty string?

Comment: @ StephenMuecke You misunderstand my mean of reload inputs! As you see in code when I reload inputs I do this: `$("#inputs").html(data);` . The previous inputs are removed and new inputs come into `#inputs Div` and not just inputs **values** are reloaded

Comment: I know that. You still have not explained what your expecting and what you actually getting

Answer (score 0):

Two most commonly used ways to reset form:

```
$("form")[0].reset();

$("form").find('input').val('');
```

Comment: But  `$("form").reset();` are not work after reloading. Problem exactly is this!

Comment: `$("form").reset();` does not work - `.reset()` is a is a DOM element method, so it would need to be `$("form")[0].reset();`. And the second option is nonsense - apart from missing textarea and select, reset works by resetting controls to their default value which may not necessarily be null

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes you are right with $("form")[0].reset(); but none of them are not work after reloading. I don't have problem by resetting form at first. Problem is after reloading the inputs